# Printer stops working after reboot

Tags: linux, printing, opensuse, cups

Problem with Samsung printer driver installation.

In a nutshell:

- one thin client (O.S Suse Linux)
- one usb printer (Samsung ml 1640)

After installing the specific manufacturer driver, the printer works perfectly except that 
after rebooting the printer itself stops working.

After some investigations I found out that the installation process puts some files under /usr/lib/cups/filter
which is a read-only dir.

I tried to set proper permission through `chmod 655 -R /usr/lib/cups/filter` but to no avail.

Does it sound correct? I mean thin clients of course are built to be diskless and everything saved then it goes away after 
rebooting but that means nothing can be installed.
This sounds strange since the manufacturer driver in tar.gz format is still there after rebooting (location: `/home/admin/Desktop`) but anything added in `/usr/lib/cups/filter` gets cancelled after restart.

Can anyone help me?
Any advice will be highly appreciated.

thanks